# running activator h2-browser can not successfully open H2 browser

Tags: playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm running **activator h2-browser** command in a ubuntu 14.04 system in a directory containing associated files of a play framework project. when that command is executed my web application is running on localhost:9000. after running **activator h2-browser** in the root directory of my project I get the following message in terminal:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /XXXX/project
[info] Set current project to XXXX (in build file:/XXX/)
TCP server running at tcp://127.0.1.1:9092 (only local connections)
PG server running at pg://127.0.1.1:5435 (only local connections)
Web Console server running at http://127.0.1.1:8082 (only local connections)
```

after executing that command 127.0.1.1:8082 is opened. I expect to see the h2-browser but actually I get *The connection was reset* on firefox.
how can I possibly fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mine worked just as said in [documention](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Developing-with-the-H2-Database):

> You can browse the contents of your database by typing h2-browser at the play console. An SQL browser will run in your web browser.

To get into *play console*, I tried `activator` first and then at the prompt, entered `h2-browser`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I had the same problem as OP, and typing in activator first then entering h2-browser worked.

Answer (score 1):

Running `activator h2-browser`
has the same effect for me as for the OP. I also tried following the statement on the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Developing-with-the-H2-Database), so I tried to [get into play console by typing "activator"](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/PlayConsole), but that seems to start the application and leaves me with three [info]s, the last being 
`a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started`
and no way to enter `h2-browser`.

**Edit: The [answer was already posted here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935726/play-framwork-running-h2-browser-works-but-the-webpage-is-not-available) Continuous mode did it for me.**