# Play! framwork: running `h2-browser` works, but the webpage is not available

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, h2

When I run the command `activator h2-browser` it opens the browser with the following url:

> 192.168.1.17:8082

But I get (using Chrome):

> This webpage is not available

The weird thing is it actually worked before. The only thing I changed since then is the `JAVA_OPTS` in order to enable debugging. I reinstalled Java and I think now there's no environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`.

Anyway, why is it happening?

**Update**
What is even more weird is that when I press view-source I get a webpage with this announcement (this is part of the webpage):

```
<h1>Welcome to H2</h1>
<h2>No Javascript</h2>
If you are not automatically redirected to the login page, then
Javascript is currently disabled or your browser does not support Javascript.
For this application to work, Javascript is essential.
Please enable Javascript now, or use another web browser that supports it.
```

But I do enable Javascript (I validated it by checking the settings, and also tried from Firefox)

**Additional information**
I'm using Java 1.8 and I don't know what was the value of `JAVA_OPTS` before I changed it, following this tutorial:  http://andikanugraha.com/2014/05/debug-typesafe-activator-play-framework-using-eclipse/

I removed Java completely and reinstall it. I think right now there's no `JAVA_OPTS` variable at all.

this is my database config:

```
db.default.driver="org.h2.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:file:main2.db" 
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
```

Comment: Does your application.conf file contain the line for db.default.url? Also, what version of Java are you using and were there any other -X flags in your JAVA_OPTS besides debug when it worked?

Comment: I updated my post, referring to your questions.

Comment: (It's unlikely that this will solve the problem, but worth a try): Did you already try clearing the browser cache, and using the URL `http://localhost:8082`? Also, this type of database URL is not recommended, as it's a relative path. I would try an absolute path, for example `jdbc:h2:file:/data/main2.db`. Then the user name `sa` should probably be in double quotes.

Comment: Didn't help. Also, when I load `view-source:http://192.168.1.17:8082/login.jsp?jsessionid=e586d9bee6d370281d692d1e0a00c194` I can actually see the source code of the login page. That's weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because the app is terminating itself immediately. I guess this is a bug in Play.

When launching it in continuous mode, everything works fine:

`activator ~h2-browser`

or

`sbt ~h2-browser`

Alternatively, you can start `activator` or `sbt` first, and from its command-line run `h2-browser`.